# searchable select box library Select2 could not work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have build a web app, need to build a searchable select box.

I have used Select2 library: https://select2.org.

But the library could not work in my case, no searchable input shows, also the breakpoint for the Select2 execution did not get hit.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id='course_for_select' name="course_for_select" style="width:200px;" class="operator">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  {% for course in query_results %}
    <option value=" {{ course.title }}">{{ course.title }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //change selectboxes to selectize mode to be searchable
    $("select").select2();
  });
</script>
```

I got the error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the console you'll see an error

> $(...).select2 is not a function

This is because although you add jquery.min.js and select2.min.js to the page, you add another instance of jQuery *after that*, which overwrites the previous one and loses the reference to Select2.

To fix the issue, simply remove the second version of jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //change selectboxes to selectize mode to be searchable
  $("select").select2();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select id='course_for_select' name="course_for_select" style="width:200px;" class="operator">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <option value=" {{ course.title }}">{{ course.title }}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I have checked the console, no such errors as u mentioned. the break point on this line: $("select").select2(); does get hit  Also after removing the second version of jQuery as your suggested, I still could not get the input box showing above the select box.

Comment: There's no error any more because you edited the code in the question to remove the second jQuery instance. The code in your question now works absolutely fine because of that. Without seeing the issue recreated, or having an error message to debug, there's not really any help we can offer.

Comment: I moved the second as you suggested, find that still no searchable input showing on my select box. Got the error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function.   I have a another script below that one, maybe that's the reason no searchable input could be find in my select box?

Comment: The code you originally posted absolutely did have an error in the console. I recreated it in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/sL3yw9jm/. Check that, and make sure you're looking in the right place to find errors. `I have a another script below that one, maybe that's the reason no searchable input could be find in my select box?`. Possible, although that script executes in your question without any errors. We can't see it working as the HTML is incomplete, though.

Comment: Fixed by changing to <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/js/select2.min.js" defer></script>

Comment: I don't see how that fixed anything given the example in both your question and my answer work fine with the latest version (4.0.13)